# mysql fetching data to cells in php

Tags: php, mysql, cells

okay so i am using this php script that works but i need to alter it heres my script.

```
<?php
$db_host = '127.0.0.1';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pwd = '';

$database = 'hit';
$table = 'Data';

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
die("Can't select database");

// sending query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
if (!$result) {
die("Query to show fields from table failed");
} 

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
$field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
echo "<tr>";

 // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
 // of $row to $cell variable
 foreach($row as $cell)
    echo "<td>$cell</td>";

echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

this works but i dont need to display my first cell

this is the mysql colum layout

```
EDITOR|PRODUCTCODE|PRICE|SIZE
```

i will be adding more colums the only colum data i do no want to display is editor but everything else i need to go into the cells

and the other problem is i want to centre the cells on my php page as at the moment they out put on the left hand side of the screen

can any one please help

Comment: `for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++) { if($i!=1){                               $field =mysql_fetch_field($result);
echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>"; }
}`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
SELECT `PRODUCTCODE`, `PRICE`, `SIZE` FROM $table
```

As for displaying the output of the query, more details on the output might be needed from you.

Comment: this is the out put that is the entire script